# How to find Radio button is checked or not in Robot framework

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

How to find is the radio button checked or not using the robot framework

For example:

```
<div>
   <label>Male</label> 
      <input name="gender" id="genderM" value="m" />
   <label>Female</label>
      <input name="gender" id="genderF" value="f" checked />
</div>
```

Comment: You can use isSelected method in WebElement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to verify

```
def is_checked(self, driver, item):
checked = driver.execute_script(("return document.getElementById('%s').checked") % item)
return checked
```

or you can use

```
driver.find_element_by_name("< check_box_name >").is_selected()
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like Robots provides some built-in functionality for this -- you can use [Checkbox Should Be Selected](http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Checkbox%20Should%20Be%20Selected):

```
Checkbox Should Be Selected | locator | Verifies checkbox locator is selected/checked.

See the Locating elements section for details about the locator syntax.
```

Comment: Checkboxes and radio buttons are very similar when looking just at HTML — I think this should work with a radio button but I may be wrong. It’s worth testing out though.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Selenium RF keyword https://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Radio%20Button%20Should%20Be%20Set%20To

```
Radio Button Should Be Set To   group_name, value
```

Verifies radio button group group_name is set to value.
group_name is the name of the radio button group.

Comment: I don't want a value of the radio button. I want to test which radio button property is checked or not. I want to test wich radio button is checked the default

Answer (score 0):

Check with keyword :

```
Element Should Be Enabled | locator
```

Comment: enabled means element is enabled or disabled?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.  HTML looked like:

```
<input class="jss816" name="visibility" type="radio" value="AdminOnly" checked="">
<input class="jss816" name="visibility" type="radio" value="Internal">
```

This Robot command returns 1 if this radio is checked:

```
get element count  css:input[name='visibility'][value='Internal']:checked
```

Not clear why this couldn't be done with an xpath, but I couldn't find a way!

Answer (score 0):

For Example:

```
<div>
       <label>Male</label> 
          <input name="gender" id="genderM" value="male" />
       <label>Female</label>
          <input name="gender" id="genderF" value="female" checked />
</div>
```

Below code is to check and select the checkbox

```
${Status}   Run Keyword And Return Status   Radio Button Should Be Set To    gender    male
```

**If ${Status} is True, then radio button male is checked, else radio button Female is checked. Based on the ${Status} we can select the required radio button using below mentioned keywords.**

```
Run Keyword If    '${Status}' == 'False'    select radio button     gender   male
Run Keyword Unless  '${Status}' == 'False'  log     Already it is selected
```